# Running Entity Framework's efbundle.exe with a SQL access token

Tags: entity-framework, azure-devops, azure-sql-database

Is it possible to migrate a database via efbundle.exe by using an access token in setups where Azure AD is in the picture?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can update to SqlClient 4.1 (or at least 3.0 or later) and use [Active Directory Default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16#using-active-directory-default-authentication) - if your pipeline account does not have access, then EnvironmentCredential looks promising.

Comment: So change the connection string to Active Directory Default and run the efbundle via AzureCli while also using the service connection?

What is EnvironmentCredential and how is it coming into play?

Comment: Have a look at the link in my reply - EnvironmentCredential could be used if the service connection does not have access to the db.

Comment: Looking foward to hearing your results!